# MySQL Function() does not work

Tags: mysql

Maybe someone can help with this query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inc_btw (prijs DECIMAL(5,2), btw DECIMAL(3,2))
    RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE inc_btw DECIMAL(10,2);
        inc_btw = (prijs*(btw+100))/100;
        RETURN inc_btw;
    END;
```

I thought it was good, but I get an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: So? Do you have an error message to accompany your question?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Rahul : can you at least tell what you have done in your answer?

Comment: @nl-x, what does exactly you mean BTW? Give it a try .. it runs with out any error. So in a single sentence solution to what OP asked.

Comment: @Rahul : Well, I'm trying to figure out what it is you have done. You just put a piece of code there with no explanation.

Comment: @nl-x, well the explanation is there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fiddling with your delimiter:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION inc_btw (prijs DECIMAL(5,2), btw DECIMAL(3,2))
    RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE inc_btw DECIMAL(10,2);
        set inc_btw = (prijs*(btw+100))/100;
        RETURN inc_btw;
    END$$
delimiter;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (prijs*(btw+100))/100;
        RETURN inc_btw;
    END' at line 6

Comment: @Fondra I think you should use `set` there. I have edited my answer, and added `set` on line 6.

Comment: @Fondra so now what is your error, after you have added `set` ?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1 

but i have that function now

Comment: yeah, you need to first drop the old function, before creating the improved one, off course. And don't forget the very last line `delimiter ;` to get back to using your default delimiter

Comment: Man.. it works. with select statement too.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (use `delimiter` and you are missing `set` in `inc_btw = (prijs*(btw+100))/100;`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION inc_btw (prijs DECIMAL(5,2), btw DECIMAL(3,2))
    RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE inc_btw DECIMAL(10,2);
        set inc_btw = (prijs*(btw+100))/100;
        RETURN inc_btw;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION inc_btw (prijs DECIMAL(5,2), btw DECIMAL(3,2))
    RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE inc_btw DECIMAL(10,2);
        set inc_btw = (prijs*(btw+100))/100;
        RETURN inc_btw;
    END$$
```